# I was trying to install wine and this appeared

Tags: wine

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-devel : Depends: wine-devel (= 9.4~mantic-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
faied@faied-HP-Laptop-14-cf2xxx:~/Desktop$
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: *deb* packages are built for specific releases; I note *mantic* or 23.10 in your paste; is that what you're using?  as without knowing what Ubuntu product/release you're using, we're somewhat limited in what help we can provide.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)